# WebStorm code completion for Firebase doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, webstorm

I am trying to build a PWA based on Firebase in WebStorm and try to get code completion for the Firebase libraries to work.

1. Added the libraries by the CDN link to my index.html.

   ```
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
   ```
2. Added the libraries to the "external libraries in WebStorm":

   [image: External libraries list]
3. Enabled them:

   [image: Enabled Firebase Libraries]
4. This is my Project structure:

   [image: Project structure]
5. Code completion doesn't work neither in `index.html` or `index.js` but execution in browser works fine. It also says that it doesn't found the functions `signOut` and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`:

   ```
   "use strict";
   function signOut() {
       firebase.auth().signOut();

   }
   function signIn(email,password) {
       firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
           console.log(error.message);
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: .js files available from CDN links are minified scrambled versions WebStorm can't use for completion:( Installing typings (`npm i @types/firebase`) helps, but installs the whole `firebase` npm package, because as of Firebase 3.2.1, the typings are included as part of it and no more distributed separately:(

Comment: is there no un minified developement version which i can use?

Comment: as far as I know, no:(